# VMware Workstation "Power off" and "Suspend" buttons are disabled. What is going on?

Tags: vmware-workstation

I've been using an XP image for a few months now with no problems.  Recently the *power off* and *resume* buttons were disabled and I'm not sure what happened to cause that.  In addition, the menu items to do those functions are grayed out (like *VM | Power | Power Off*)

I'm using VMware Workstation 6.5.3 on a Windows 7 64-bit host.  The image is Windows XP 32-bit.  There is plenty of free space and memory on the host and the CPU is not pegged.

I am able to power off the image through its Start menu, but that's a workaround not a fix.

Any suggestions?  TIA

EDIT: Well after manually shutting down the image then closing and reopening the image file (which I've done before) in preparation for reinstalling the tools as suggested below, it looks fine.  The power off and suspend buttons are enabled and work.

So what do I do with this question now?  "Close and restart a few times and it may work" doesn't seem useful...

Comment: Are those machines shared?

Answer (score 1):

Try reinstalling VMware Tools on your VM. I guess is that something's in a weird state. Reinstalling is a good general method of ruling that out. It's easy to try, at any rate.

Answer (score 1):

**There are a couple of reasons they might be disabled:**

1. It's in the middle of doing a snapshot/backup
2. VMware Tools is not properly configured/service isn't started/etc
3. Host machine process is running into issues. (VMware.exe process not acting properly)

The best resolution you can do if you don't want to restart the image is to restart the VMware tools service. It frequently runs into issues and it should solve 99% of your issues.

If it is in the middle of a snapshot or something, your best course of action is to just wait.

Finally, if the VMware.exe process is having some funny behaviour, the best thing you can do is to close out the program and use the task manager to kill the process.

Answer (score 0):

Someone may have enabled the Administrative Lockout features of VMWare.  This allows you to configure, on a per image basis, the menu functions that are available, including disabling all the Power options, i.e.  Shutdown and Power Off.